# CakePHP: Is there a easy way to send custom status code and send serialized vars in controller?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm building a restful API in a controller. I want to respond to GET resources that do not exist with a 404 status response and send a message in JSON. Like this:

```
public function view($id = null)
  $this->request->allowMethod(['get']);
  try {
    $pessoa = $this->Users->get($id);
  } catch (RecordNotFoundException $e){
    $this->set(['message'=>'User not found']);
    return $response->withStatus(404);
  }
  $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

But it does not returns the message. I guess this 'return' interferes on the variable definitions flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use Cakephp 3.x

See [Response](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#response) section on CookBook.

And try it:

```
$this->response = $this->response->withStatus(404);
```

Comment: It does the same as my example. Don't return the JSON data. But works without return statement. Thanks.

Comment: on section link, you can see how send all data with status header. i suggest you see friendsofcake how or this [link](http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-build-a-cakephp-3-rest-api-in-minutes/) by bravo kernel.